# How urllib2 connect the internet in the source code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I open the file in path: Python->Lib->urllib2.py,and read it,
but i cannot find the code which specifies the details of connecting the aim website server.
the most close is the **call__chain** function in the picture below.[result=html content if i comprehend rightly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfcmb.png)
Are the details hidden?
Waiting for a solution online.

Comment: Did you have a look on Github ? https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/urllib2.py

Comment: Most of the work is done in the `httplib` module. See the code in [`HTTPConnection`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.12/Lib/httplib.py#l725).

Comment: Pycharm (beside others) has a really nice debugger - add a breakpoint into code, and then use the debugger to go through the code step by step.